# How to change UserControl in background?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am stuck with a problem where I want to change user control on different events in background. I am new in MVVM but I am bound to use MVVM only to achive this task. Code structure is little complex to me but still I figured that New Employee form is getting shown on button click but in new window but I want that form to be opened in current window's content. Code is given here which I need to modify to open usercontrol.

```
public Task<bool?> InitModification(CoreViewModel vm)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool?>();

        _dispatcherService.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            bool? result = null;
            Window activeWindow = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < Application.Current.Windows.Count; i++)
            {
                var win = Application.Current.Windows[i];
                if ((win != null) && (win.IsActive))
                {
                    activeWindow = win;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (activeWindow != null)
            {
                var win = new NewEmp(vm) { Owner = activeWindow };
                result = win.ShowDialog();
            }

            tcs.SetResult(result);
        }));


        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, you could replace the for loop by `var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);`

Comment: Create user controls or data templates hat will be the views for all the view models you want to switch/toggle in your main window. In your main window, use a ContentControl which will be responsible for displaying the different VM. Create different data templates in the ContentControl's resource dictionary whose target type matches the class of the VMs (and which contain the UserControls you made). In your main VM, declare a property that you use to set and keep track of the view model you want to display in the ContentControl. Bind the ContentControl's Content property to this property...

Comment: @elgonzo: I have done these all steps but getting confused in place of 'var win = new NewEmp(vm) { Owner = activeWindow };
                result = win.ShowDialog();' what should I return.?

Comment: Well, ask yourself, what is this line doing precisely? What is NewEmp? What is the method ShowDialog doing? How does it fit into your plan?

Comment: @elgonzo: Well my concern is here that I need to set content of ContentControl from here but in existing it is showing the window which I dont want.

Comment: What you should do in my opinion i wrote already in my first comment :)

Comment: @RaviKantHudda When working with MVVM and using `databinding` you don't need to return anything to the ViewModel. Just set properties based on the value that you "receive" from the method.

Comment: @Bojje: I am newbie in MVVM. Can u just elaborate how to set content of contentcontrol in this function?

Answer (score 0):

My answer will not use your code since I don't find it useful to what you want to achieve. My answer will suffice with a suggestion on how you can achieve changing content control with MVVM

The way I go about it is with every MVVM-project I have a "application-shell" that acts as a wrapper for all my other content and through that you can easily change content. This application is a View and a ViewModel like such.

**ShellView**

```
<xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WhereOurViewModelIs.ViewModel">
<!--More XAML code-->
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MyViewModel}">
    <Views:MyView/>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:AnotherViewModel}">
    <Views:AnotherView/>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel
{
  private BaseViewModel _currentPage{get;set;}

  Public BaseViewModel CurrentPage{
      get{return _currentPage;}
      set{_currentPage = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
  }

  public ShellViewModel
  {
    CurrentPage = new MyViewModel();
  }
}
```

Since we don't know how many different pages there is (in theory) we will tell them that need to be a of a type (inherited or an object) of BaseViewModel. This way we don't need to check for every single page and remove redundant code.

Then you set the `Datacontext = new ShellViewModel();` in behind code of ShellView.xaml

**BaseViewModel**

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
  /*This class can contains whatever you want your other ViewModels to be able to do*/
}
```

Now you need to set up 2 ViewModels with 2 Views just like we did with our shell.

**MyViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
  /*Contains Properties,methods,private fields. What you want to show on view*/
}
```

**AnotherViewModel**

```
public class AnotherViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
  /*Contains Properties,methods,private fields. What you want to show on view*/
}
```

Now you can set event to your ShellViewModel to change content whenever something happens. Hopefully this can atleast give you some idea how to work with MVVM. Of course you need to set up our ViewModels with properties changed event and other to get everything working, but this is a start for you.

If you find this answer helpful please chose it as an answer since it take some time to make an example like this.